# Github Workflow Actions: git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: github-actions, maven-release-plugin

I'd like to setup a GitHub Action to Release and deploy to Maven Central. I tried several approaches but in the end it always fails with:

```
Error:  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project homeautomation-parent: Unable to commit files
Error:  Provider message:
Error:  The git-push command failed.
Error:  Command output:
Error:  git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
Error:  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I expected that with the GITHUB_TOKEN this should work. What am I missing? Do I need to create a SSH Token for actions@github.com or use my personal one?

```
GITHUB_TOKEN Permissions
  Actions: write
  Checks: write
  Contents: write
  Deployments: write
  Discussions: write
  Issues: write
  Metadata: read
  Packages: write
  Pages: write
  PullRequests: write
  RepositoryProjects: write
  SecurityEvents: write
  Statuses: write
```

I created the following workflow file:

```
name: Publish package to the Maven Central Repository

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      releaseVersion:
        description: "Define the release version"
        required: true
        default: ""
      developmentVersion:
        description: "Define the snapshot version"
        required: true
        default: ""

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4    
    - run: |
        git config user.email "actions@github.com"
        git config user.name "GitHub Actions"
    - name: Set up Maven Central Repository
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        distribution: 'temurin'
        java-version: '17'
        server-id: ossrh # Value of the distributionManagement/repository/id field of the pom.xml
        server-username: MAVEN_USERNAME # env variable for username in deploy
        server-password: MAVEN_PASSWORD # env variable for token in deploy
        gpg-private-key: ${{ secrets.MAVEN_GPG_PRIVATE_KEY }} # Value of the GPG private key to import
        gpg-passphrase: MAVEN_GPG_PASSPHRASE # env variable for GPG private key passphrase

    - name: Release & Publish to Apache Maven Central
      run: mvn -U -B -Prelease release:prepare release:perform -DreleaseVersion=${{ github.event.inputs.releaseVersion }} -DdevelopmentVersion=${{ github.event.inputs.developmentVersion }} deploy
      env:
        MAVEN_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.OSSRH_USERNAME }}
        MAVEN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.OSSRH_TOKEN }}
        MAVEN_GPG_PASSPHRASE: ${{ secrets.MAVEN_GPG_PASSPHRASE }}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  ~ Copyright 2021-2021 the original author or authors.
  ~
  ~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  ~ you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~
  ~       https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  ~ WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  ~ See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  ~ limitations under the License.
  -->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.github.davemeier82.homeautomation</groupId>
    <artifactId>homeautomation-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}</name>
    <description>HomeAutomation parent POM</description>
    <url>https://github.com/davemeier82/homeautomation-parent</url>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
            <url>https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>David Meier</name>
            <email>davidmeier1@gmail.com</email>
            <organization>David Meier</organization>
            <organizationUrl>https://github.com/davemeier82</organizationUrl>
        </developer>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/davemeier82/homeautomation-parent.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/davemeier82/homeautomation-parent.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/davemeier82/homeautomation-parent</url>
        <tag>homeautomation-parent-0.2.3-SNAPSHOT</tag>
    </scm>
    <issueManagement>
        <system>GitHub</system>
        <url>https://github.com/davemeier82/homeautomation-parent/issues</url>
    </issueManagement>

    <properties>
        <java.release>17</java.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <spring-boot.version>3.0.6</spring-boot.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.10.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-source-plugin.version>3.2.1</maven-source-plugin.version>
        <maven-javadoc-plugin.version>3.4.1</maven-javadoc-plugin.version>
        <maven-gpg-plugin.version>3.0.1</maven-gpg-plugin.version>
        <nexus-staging-maven-plugin.version>1.6.13</nexus-staging-maven-plugin.version>
        <maven-release-plugin.version>2.5.3</maven-release-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <release>${java.release}</release>
                        <compilerArgs>
                            <arg>-parameters</arg>
                        </compilerArgs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-source-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-sources</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <!-- Javadoc -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-javadoc-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <!-- GPG -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-gpg-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>sign</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                              <gpgArguments>
                                <arg>--pinentry-mode</arg>
                                <arg>loopback</arg>
                              </gpgArguments>
                          </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${nexus-staging-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <configuration>
                        <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
                        <nexusUrl>https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                        <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-release-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <url>https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <url>https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add private SSH key to ssh-agent. introduce this step right after checkout step. You need to create ssh key pair using ssh-keygen and place it in github secrets.

```
- uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.8.0
  with:
       ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
```

More about ssh-agent action --> https://github.com/marketplace/actions/webfactory-ssh-agent